# Problems setting Tomcat Java Heap Size to 8GB on Windows 7 (64 bit)?

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory

I need larger Java Heap Size atleast 8GB minimum for my search application. I am working on Windows 7 (64 bit). I am not able to allocate more than 1500MB using CATALINA_OPTS environment variable. When I try allocating more the Tomcat crashes and is not able to start. I donwloaded 64 bit Java Run Time now and also subsequently 64 bit Apache Tomcat. Even now its not permitting me to start with more Heap Size. It (Tomcat 64 bit) crashes again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any log messages prior to the crash?

Comment: Please post crash stack trace.

Comment: Why do you need larger heap size? Is Tomcat unable to run your app with this heap size? If yes whats the error?

Comment: See if this is impacting you http://stackoverflow.com/a/497757/324900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. Actually I was trying to start Tomcat (startup.bat) in command prompt in Windows. It was crashing. Still dont know the reason for this (maybe related to starting 64 bit Tomcat on Dos/ When I start tomcat as a service using service.bat install it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Increasing the JVM maximum heap size for memory intensive applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications)

Try to specify `-d64` on your `CATALINA_OPTS`.

**Edit:** Seems that option only has an effect on Solaris. Nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

let the environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` refer to your 64-Bit JVM. You can check it on command-line by executing `java -version` and `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version` (on Windows).