# Derby DB Backup

Tags: sql, database, derby

Currently I am backing up my Derby Database using the `SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE` procedure. However due to a too big size sometimes this fails and I am wondering if there exist the possibility to backup only data that is newer than `x` days, where `x` is a settable values.

Would appreciate greatly any hints towards achieving this goal, if that is possible.

Comment: I don't think Derby supports this. So you'd have to write some sort of procedure to implement this, which would probably not be a good idea as it would be error prone. You could solve the problem with more hardware though. Can you buy a second disk and write your backups to that device?

Comment: What is the failure message?

Comment: Sometimes it fails due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Give it more memory! Your JVM should have a flag that lets you specify a larger amount of memory for your program. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications