# Error occured during initialization of VM: Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting below error on starting SonarQube:
Error occured during initialixation of VM: Could not reserve enough space for memory heap

Also modified wrapper.conf underSonarQube conf folder, but didn't work.
Also changed java version: Java 8 to Java 7, didn't work

Comment: Increase your JVM heap memory size. Here is example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications

Comment: You are trying to give the JVM more memory than you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with version mismatch of plugins installed in sonarqube. I deleted jars for all plugins except java. This solved the issue.
I figured it out from sonar.log
Thanks

Comment: Running with the C# plugin, I had to delete the Java plugin to get it to work. So same solution, but true for other languages.

Answer (score 2):

You do not enough available memory to run SonarQube. Try closing some applications.

If this is not enough check whether SonarQube's startup script specifies the amount of memory required, e.g. with options like `-Xms=??? -Xmx=???`. These indicate roughly the minimum and maximum amount of memory Java will acquire. Note the actual values and check with the task manager if you have enough memory available.

Comment: I have restarted my system many times and no other application is up.

Answer (score 0):

Its due to lack of memory. if you are trying that with ANT try the following

```
set ANT_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

Comment: No. I am starting sonarqube with SinarQube.bat file