# Data Source Connection Error in IBM Cognos BI 10

Tags: java, postgresql, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I am trying to connect the below listed from the IBM COGNOS BI 10 through JDBC Drivers

1. Connect **LUW system** which is having **Postgresql**,  but I was getting error like 
   **" XQE-JDB-0004 A problem occurred finding the driver class "org.postgresql.Driver" "**.
2. Connecting **BIGSQL server** .I was getting an error  **"XQE-ROL-0183 Insufficient memory. The current JVM maximum heap size of the QueryService is 972MB and may need to be increased: Java heap space"** , then I increased the heap size to 1536MB(previously it was 1024MB) but then I was facing another issue

> "DPR-ERR-2002 Unable to execute the request because there were no
>   connections to the process available within the configured time
>   limit.**
>
> Handler trace back [the_dispatcher]
>   com.cognos.pogo.handlers.performance.PerformanceIndicationHandler
>   [the_dispatcher] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler
>   [service_lookup] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.engine.ServiceLookupHandler
>   [load_balancer] com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler
>   [lb_forwarder] com.cognos.p2plb.cler
>
> ver.LoadBalanceHandler [queryChainHandler]
>   com.cognos.pogo.handlers.logic.ChainHandler [queryAsyncHandler]
>   com.cognos.pogo.async.impl.AsyncHandler [queryServiceHandler]
>   com.cognos.xqebifw.cubingservices.CubingServicesHandler "

then I increased the **Queue time limit of report service in Query Services** but still I had the same issue. Then I reset the Query Service settings values to default value but I still facing the same issue **DPR-ERR-2002**.

3. Connecting **z/OS DB2**, I successfully created the Data Source connection in IBM Administration but in **Metadata Wizard - Select Data Source(in IBM Frame Work Manager)** step after selecting the created Data source if i gave next option the tool was not responding, so i was not able to create project for the same, I have attached the screen shot for the same.

[image]

Kindly help me how to solve this issue and also let me know the **jar files to be added for Postgresql**.

Comment: For 2 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications

Comment: For 1 see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/