# Getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError regarding the JavaMaximumHeapSize in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 for an Android project

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

I am trying to build an Android project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on Windows 10. I get this error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -jar ...

How can I increase the `JavaMaximumHeapSize` in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015?

As suggested in other answers, I went to *Project Properties -> Android Options -> Advanced*, but I did not see a MaximumHeapSize field.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications

Comment: Remove error headers, clarify title, improve English

Comment: Clarify title, remove error headers, format error, improve English, format navigation