# MAVEN_OPTS ignored when setting java heap size

Tags: java, maven

How is this possible? I do not understand linux correctly because I do not 
know how this can happen.  I believe there is something else happening here as im trying to set the max heap size to 1G and it is failing

The MAVEN_OPTS specify a heap of  1024m but the maven command fails because the heap is 4096m. The machine is 32 bit with 6G installed

Memory

```
$free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5.8G       3.8G       2.0G       186M       351M       2.1G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.3G       4.4G
Swap:         5.8G         0B       5.8G
```

Maven

```
echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

$ mvn -version
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Java

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

Linux

```
uname -a 102-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 14:28:35 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increasing the JVM maximum heap size for memory intensive applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030263/increasing-the-jvm-maximum-heap-size-for-memory-intensive-applications)

Comment: thanks i looked at that before. I believe there is something else happening here as im trying to set themax heap size to 1G and it is failing

Comment: what is the output of `which mvn`?  Is it a shell script?  What are its contents?

Comment: What's the Maven command? How does it crash (what error do you see)?

Answer (score 3):

Set again with below and try:

Linux:

> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Windows

> set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Comment: same result. It seems the value for heap size is being set somewhere else but I cant think of a place which takes prescience over the  bash session cli.

Comment: check in configuration file - ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

Comment: Ever checked JAVA_OPTS ?

Comment: check system environment variable MAVEN_OPTS values

Comment: Yeah I checked JAVA_OPTS, echo $JAVA_OPTS showed me it is unset.

Comment: Hi, the Windows  command is incorrect. It should be `set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`.

Also, `MaxPermSIze` is ignored in Java 8+. The new setting is `-XX:maxMetaspace=1024m`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this same error, and the solution was provided to my via [this blog post](http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.ca/2014/03/maven-invalid-maximum-heap-size.html). In the post, it is stated;

> Check mvn.bat: the MAVEN_OPTS is passed as JVM parameter directly:
>
> SET MAVEN_JAVA_EXE="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" %MAVEN_JAVA_EXE%
>   %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath %CLASSWORLDS_JAR%
>   "-Dclassworlds.conf=%M2_HOME%\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.home=%M2_HOME%"
>   %CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
>
> If we run set MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M",the previous
>   command would be replaced with %MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% "-Xmx1024M
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M" ...
>
> If we run java "-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxermSize=256M" -version: we will see
>   same error message.
>
> The solution is simple:  We can run: set "MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"  or remove the double quotes completely: set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M
>
> The value of MAVEN_OPTS would be with no surrounding double quotes.

This certainly addressed my issue.