# Clojure GC overhead limit exceeded when using iterate

Tags: java, clojure, garbage-collection

Apologies for duplicates but I haven't been able to solve this issue from reading other posts. I am trying to run a computationally intensive iterative algorithm. The next iterate is given by a function "update" and I collect all the iterates via

```
(def iterates (doall (take 1000 (iterate update initial-state))))
```

where initial-state is the zeroeth iterate with which I am initializing the algorithm. Unfortunately I cannot supply a minimal example... update is quite a complicated function which takes a map datastructure as input and outputs an updated map datastructure. Code runs fine for total iterations up to 800 but then produces the error below for anything larger. General opinion is that merely increasing the size available to the garbage collector is not sufficient, as this is symptomatic of a deeper problem (perhaps). In other posts the problem presented are very specific, yet my update function is very complex. How then can I go about solving this in the generality provided here? Are there certain tooling utilities I can use?

1. Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   GC overhead limit exceeded

   ```
          Double.java:  519  java.lang.Double/valueOf
         Numbers.java:  611  clojure.lang.Numbers$DoubleOps/multiply
         Numbers.java:  148  clojure.lang.Numbers/multiply
             core.clj:   21  ssm4clj.core/corr
             core.clj:    6  ssm4clj.core/corr
             core.clj:   42  ssm4clj.core/innovation
             core.clj:   40  ssm4clj.core/innovation
             core.clj: 2522  clojure.core/partial/fn
             core.clj: 2646  clojure.core/map/fn
         LazySeq.java:   40  clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval
         LazySeq.java:   49  clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq
              RT.java:  521  clojure.lang.RT/seq
             core.clj:  137  clojure.core/seq
             core.clj: 2654  clojure.core/map/fn
         LazySeq.java:   40  clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval
         LazySeq.java:   49  clojure.lang.LazySeq/seq
            Cons.java:   39  clojure.lang.Cons/next
              RT.java:  688  clojure.lang.RT/next
             core.clj:   64  clojure.core/next
        protocols.clj:  168  clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:  124  clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:   19  clojure.core.protocols/fn/G
        protocols.clj:   31  clojure.core.protocols/seq-reduce
        protocols.clj:   75  clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:   75  clojure.core.protocols/fn
        protocols.clj:   13  clojure.core.protocols/fn/G
             core.clj: 6545  clojure.core/reduce
             core.clj: 6527  clojure.core/reduce
             core.clj:  347  ssm4clj.core/mean-conditional
             core.clj:  319  ssm4clj.core/mean-conditional
                 REPL:  332  ipp4clj.multiplexing/update-single-gp-mean
                 REPL:  329  ipp4clj.multiplexing/update-single-gp-mean
   ```

Comment: How much memory would a set of 1000 states take up? Is it possible that you simply don't have enough RAM to hold this much data and the additional garbage that is created by the calculations that you're doing?

Comment: Do you need all the states or maybe just one that reaches a goal? I wonder if you could use `drop` as well as `take` to discard states as you go along?? Or `drop-while` combined with `first`?

Comment: @SamEstep, when I "top" the process, the percentage in the %MEM columns is around 30 for process in question. Checking the docs of top, %MEM displays the task's currently used share of available physical memory. It is my understanding that the process is only using 30% of my RAM.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Unfortunately in this application I need all the iterates.

Comment: @Lindon Ah yes, you're right; I had forgotten that there were other limits for JVM memory. How much does 30% of your RAM amount to? You may need to increase the maximum heap size as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3067285/5044950). But my question still stands: how much memory would a set of 1000 states take up? Since you haven't specified your state structure and `update` function, we can't really make judgments without that sort of information.

Comment: @SamEstep The machine upon which I'm running this code has 16GB of RAM (obtained from executing `free -mt` in a terminal). I did not find an easy way of querying the size of an object from inside the clojure repl, so lets for the sake of argument assume that 1000 states takes up a lot of memory. If this is the case, what would you suggest I do? Manually increase the maximum heap size?

Comment: @Lindon OK, yeah; generally speaking, the only thing I can think of would be to manually increase the maximum heap size; if you could give more information on your state structure and `update` function, or find a way to figure out a rough estimate of how much memory would be taken up by 1000 states, I or someone else could potentially give advice on how optimize, but it looks like you're probably going to need to increase your maximum heap size.

Comment: Do 500 iterations, send them off (or store them) but keeping the last one, then go again for the next 500 (or maybe smaller amount if the data structures are getting bigger) using the last from last time as the first from this time. Also the data structures could be made more canonical (i.e. take up less space and be more suited to the problem). Also JVM memory of course.

Comment: Have tried to look into the running JVM process with jvisualvm? With Oracle JDK it is included, with OpenJDK it is usually a separate package.

Answer (score 1):

To go along with @StefanKamphausen's comment. I think jvisualvm would also help you out quite a bit. [Here](https://vimeo.com/27237005/) is a walk through of usage.